# I'm trying to connect to the DB, but the connect() function doesn't seem to work

Tags: mysql, node.js, console, database-connection, node.js-connect

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
// const mysql = require('mysql')
const mysql = require('./db')()
const cors = require('cors')
require('dotenv').config(); 
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`${port}`))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send("hi")
})

const connection = mysql.init()
mysql.open(connection)
```

This is my server.js code.

```
const mysql = require('mysql')
require('dotenv').config(); 

module.exports = function() {
  return {
    init: function () {
      return mysql.createConnection({
        host: process.env.HOST,
        user: process.env.USER,
        password: process.env.PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.DATABASE,
        port: process.env.PORT
      })
    },

    open: function(con) {
      con.connect(function(err) {
        // if (err) throw err
        // console.log('Connected!')
        if(err) {
          console.log('mysql connection error: '+err)
        } else {
          console.log('mysql is connected successfully.')
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my db.js code... 
I expect the port number and message "mysql is connected successfully" to be printed when this code is executed. But when I run it, nothing is output except for the port number. Not even an error message. 
So I can't verify that the database connection was made properly. Why is the contents of the connect() function not executed?

[image: What is output to the console when the code is executed]

Comment: can you console env variables: process.env.HOST if they are set

Comment: @Yilmaz I'm sorry, but I didn't quite understand what you meant. Are you saying go to the host address and check the console?

Comment: `console.log("host value:",process.env.HOST)`

Comment: @Yilmaz When I run it, "localhost" is output to the console.

Comment: in db.connect you have `// console.log('Connected!')`. can you uncomment this. if that function is running it should log "Connected"

Comment: @Yilmaz Sorry, but even if I uncomment it, only the port number is still output... If the console statement that outputs that host is also put in the connect() function, the execution value does not come out, so I executed it outside. . In this case, is the connection not being established properly?

Comment: what is operating system

Comment: @Yilmaz It's windows !!

Comment: can you write connection code in a separate file. then export db `module.exports = db`. in the above  main file, require it `require('../database')`

Comment: @Yilmaz Thank you for continuing to help. As you said, I modified the server.js code by writing a separate db.js code, but the result is still the same. It only outputs the port number...

Comment: dont run it. just require it `require('./db')`

Comment: @Yilmaz If () is not appended, it will not be executed with an error "mysql.init is not a function"...!! But if I add (), it runs normally.

Comment: @Yilmaz The answer below solved the problem... I made a stupid mistake... Still, thank you so much for your help!!!

Comment: I saw it. good job. you should be accepting the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used same environment variable for server port and database port. Please change variable name `PORT` of database port to `DB_PORT` in .env file. Then change the environment variable name in the database port of db.js file as well.

`db.js`

```
const mysql = require("mysql");
require("dotenv").config();

module.exports = function () {
  return {
    init: function () {
      return mysql.createConnection({
        host: process.env.HOST,
        user: process.env.USER,
        password: process.env.PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.DATABASE,
        port: process.env.DB_PORT,
      });
    },

    open: function (con) {
      con.connect(function (err) {
        // if (err) throw err
        // console.log('Connected!')
        if (err) {
          console.log("mysql connection error: " + err);
        } else {
          console.log("mysql is connected successfully.");
        }
      });
    },
  };
};
```

`example .env file`

```
PORT=8080
HOST=localhost
USER=root
PASSWORD=root
DATABASE=dbname
DB_PORT=3306
```

Comment: Huh... How could I make such a mistake... Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Could you please make this as accepted answer if it's helpful. 

Comment: How did I missed that :) +1

Comment: I accepted it!! Thank you!!!